# Matching a sequence within a sequence in scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm looking to match a sequence within a sequence like either in ex 1 or ex 2;

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4) match {
  case 1 :: List(_*) :: 4 :: tail => // Ex 1
  case 1 :: (seq : List[Int]) :: 4 :: tail => // Ex 2
  case _ => 
}
```

This is a variant to the [fixed length sequence pattern `_*`](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#lst:fixed-sequence). Like the `_*`, I don't care about the content of the inner pattern, but it is important that the length can vary and that the pattern is surrounded by a prefix (such as the `1` above) and a suffix (like the `4`).

My question is if any of you have a trick to do this by some crafty `unapply` magic or if you'd just iterate the list to search for the sequence manually.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really outside the scope of what pattern matching is supposed to be used for.  Even if you could finagle a set of custom `unapply` methods to do what you wanted, it wouldn't be apparent whether matching was greedy or not, etc..

However, if you really want to, you can proceed as follows (for example):

```
import scala.collection.SeqLike
class Decon[A](a0: A, a1: A) {
  def unapply[C <: SeqLike[A, C]](xs: C with SeqLike[A, C]): Option[(C, C)] = {
     xs.span(_ != a1) match {
       case (a0 +: pre, a1 +: post) => Some((pre,post))
       case _ => None
     }
   }
}
val Dc = new Decon(1,4)

scala> List(1,2,3,4,5) match { case Dc(pre, post) => (pre, post); case _ => (Nil, Nil) }
res1: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(2, 3),List(5))
```

Separating the specification of the fixed elements `1` and `4` from the match is necessary; otherwise the normal algorithm would ask the `unapply` to return values without any knowledge of what was being sought, and then would test to make sure they were correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And some impressive programming there :-) I think it'll work with your solution, but I agree with your argument; this requires a bit too much magic. I think I'll work on some recursive solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
List(1,2,3,4) match {
    case 1 :: tail if tail.last == 4 => println("Found it!")
  }
```

But if you check the implementation of `last` in `LinearSeqOptimized`:

```
  def last: A = {
    if (isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException
    var these = this
    var nx = these.tail
    while (!nx.isEmpty) {
      these = nx
      nx = nx.tail
    }
    these.head
  }
```

It is iterating indeed. This is because `List` inherits from `LinearSeq` which are optimized to provide efficient `head` and `tail` operations. For what you want to do, it is better to use an `IndexedSeq` implementation like `Vector` which has an optimized `length` operation, used in `last`:

```
override /*TraversableLike*/ def last: A = {
    if (isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.last")
    apply(length-1)
  }
```

So you could do something like this:

```
Vector(1,2,3,4) match {
    case v if v.head == 1 && v.last == 4 => println("Found it!")
  }
```

Comment: Great answer! I was hoping to use pattern matching to avoid doing this, so I gave Rex the points. However, as I wrote in the comment, it'll probably be something like this I'll end up doing. So thanks :-)

Comment: This doesn't actually work the way the pattern match does, because you don't catch the rest of the tail after the `4`.  You'd need an `indexOf` or `find` or `span` or something.